# database (firestore) call is only taking the first value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to make a call the database (firestore) to return the data of the products in real time that the user has added them to the cart then this data will be used in a code to get the total price of the cart items so I have tried the following approach:

**This `useEfect`** **will get make the database call and will set the items state to to an array of objects that contains the id and quantity of each cart item on real time**

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState([]);
const [Total, setTotal] = useState(0);
const oneSubTotal = [];

useEffect(() => {
  db.collection("users").doc("4sfrRMB5ROMxXDvmVdwL").collection("basket").onSnapshot((docs) => {
    let array = []
    docs.forEach(doc =>{
      array.push(doc.data())
      console.log(array)
      setItems(array)
    })
  });
}, [])
```

This code should loop through the items array to add an  the element `item.price` to each object after getting the price of each item by another call to the database then it push to the Subtotal array the total price of each item by pushing the quantity multiplied by the price

```
useEffect(() => {
  items && items.forEach((item) => {
    // console.log(item)
    const id = item.id
    db.collection("products").doc(id).get().then((e)=>{
      item.price = (e.data().price)
      oneSubTotal.push(item.price * item.quantity)
      setSubTotal(oneSubTotal)
    })
})
```

then this code will loop through the subtotal array to get the sum of the price of the items

```
let sum = 0; 
for (let num of subTotal){
  sum = sum + num
}
useEffect(() => {
  setTotal(sum)
}, [sum, items])
```

but the issue is the value of  `Total` when the page renders first time  always will be the total price of the first item which is represented with the first object in the items array and when I modify the quantity of any item **(without refreshing the page)** the `Total` value shows the correct amount for few  seconds then the value of it returns to show the first items total price only

Answer (score 0):

In your `onSnapshot` handler, you are calling `console.log(array)` and `setItems(array)` prematurely. This potentially causes your app to be rendered multiple times. You should make sure to be calling these lines outside of the `forEach` loop.

```
.onSnapshot((docs) => {
  let array = []
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    array.push(doc.data())
  });
  console.log(array)
  setItems(array)
});
```

But even so, it would be more efficient to fetch the item prices before calling `setItems`. Plus, instead of calling out to the database one-by-one using `forEach`, you should bundle the requests into batches like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66880525/3068190) which is available as a utility function, [`fetchDocumentsWithId()`](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/aea3bc9481bbab0a7fbc72069940e527).

```
.onSnapshot((docs) => {
  const cartItems = [], itemPriceObject = {};
  // cartItems will be ({ id: string, quantity: number, price: number | null, lineTotal: number })[]
  // itemPriceObject will be a map of IDs to their price (a Record<string, number | null>) (used to deduplicate IDs & store prices)
  
  docs.forEach(doc => {
    const cartItem = doc.data()
    cartItems.push(cartItem)
    itemPriceObject[cartItem.id] = null
  });
  
  // idsArray is a deduplicated list of IDs
  const idsArray = Object.keys(itemPriceObject);
  
  fetchDocumentsWithId(
    db.collection("products"),
    idsArray,
    (itemDoc) => {
      itemPriceObject[itemDoc.id] = itemDoc.get("price") // more efficient than itemDoc.data().price
    }
  )
    .then(() => {
      // if here, all prices (that are available) have been retrieved
      // MAY BE NULL! Consider these items to be "not available"

      const totalSum = 0
      
      // put prices in their items, calculate line cost and add to total
      cartItems.forEach(item => {
        item.price = itemPriceObject[item.id]
        item.lineTotal = item.price === null ? 0 : item.price * item.quantity
        totalSum += item.lineTotal
      }
      
      // set items & total sum
      setItems(cartItems)
      setTotal(totalSum)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // failed to retrieve some documents from the database
      // TODO: update UI
    });
});
```

**Note:** For clarity, `subTotal` (meaning: the sum of some, but not all values) was renamed to `lineTotal` (meaning: the cost of items in this entry/line, the `cost x quantity`)